# If a browser's element inspector says the width of an element is 300px, can I be sure that it'll be the same across all browsers?

Tags: html, css, browser

[image: screenshot]

---

In the screenshot above, Google Chrome's (element/web) inspector tool shows that the dimensions of a menu-item are 547 by 308 pixels.

Now, can I be sure that all modern browsers (IE9 and above, Chrome, Opera, Firefox) also recognize the menu-item by those very same dimensions? If not, how does it vary? (e.g. font-rendering?)

**EDIT:** I do you use a CSS reset stylesheet. To be more specific, I use [Normalize.css](http://necolas.github.com/normalize.css/), which is quite popular.

Comment: You can't be sure unless you are using a very good CSS Reset/Normalize.

Comment: @Jawad Yes indeed. I am using [Normalize.css](https://github.com/necolas/normalize.css/) v1.0.2.

Comment: In that case, they should have the same dimensions. You should also have a look at the box-sizing property and make sure a default value for this property is included in your CSS Reset/Normalize.

Comment: @Jawad Yes, I see `box-sizing` for `button, html, input` elements in my Reset CSS. [See for yourself](https://raw.github.com/necolas/normalize.css/master/normalize.css).

Comment: Than you have narrowed down your aim to 90%. But as @cimmanon, there are just too many factors involved of which, I am sure, you are aware of. Screen size, Device used, Fonts installed, Media etc...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you specified `width: 547px; height: 308px` then no.  If you're allowing the element to shrink and grow based on the size of the descendant elements (and the descendant's dimensions are not constrained by a fixed width or height), then it will vary.

You can never be certain how the user has configured their browser in terms of font-size (some users like a larger font-size so it is easier to read).  You can't even be certain the user has the font-family specified, and their default font-face might have wider or narrower glyphs than what you're expecting.

Comment: Indeed the font may differ on each browser even on the same system as each browser has its own font rendering engine and sometimes, in rare cases, it may add or subtract a few pixels.

Answer (score 4):

You can't be sure. The reason is that browsers have what are called *user agent stylesheets*. These are default styles that the browser can set to be, well, whatever they want. As an example, Chrome's user agent stylesheet defines top and bottom margin on `p` tags.

To ensure that you're displaying things the same, you need to overwrite the user agent stylesheets. The best way to do this is to use what's called a CSS reset stylesheet, which try to remove any properties the browser has defined.

You can read all about user agent stylesheets [here](http://meiert.com/en/blog/20070922/user-agent-style-sheets/). And [here are some CSS reset stylesheets](http://www.cssreset.com/).

Comment: What about the different box models across different browsers? Won't that affect the size returned?

Comment: @Deleteman only specific older versions of IE use a "different box model".  Changing the box-model only changes how the browser calculates the finished "box" dimensions by calculating (or not calculating) in the margins/paddings/borders.